# Sanitise/Remove emojis from all requests type before requesting to server

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I need to remove emojies from the request body (json type) before sending it to the server, like we can sanitise headers while using Logger. so far I know we can intercept the request like this

```
      HttpClient {
        ......
        .....
      }.plugin(HttpSend).intercept { request ->
        val originalCall = execute(request)
        val contentType = originalCall.request.content.contentType
        val isJson: Boolean = contentType == ContentType("application", "json")
        if (isJson) {
          //how to find and remove emojis from the body
          //then execute(sanitised request)
        } else {
          originalCall
        }
```

is there a better way to do this please share thanks

Comment: You'd need to walk the data and check if each character is an emoji, removing it if it is.  There's a variety of libraries out there in Java (and probably some in kotlin) you can use to determine if a character is an emoji, but there's nothing built into the language

Comment: This might help, [a list of emojis' code points](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AEmoji%3DYes%3A%5D&esc=on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sanitize the request body you can determine the type of the `HttpRequestBuilder.body` property and create a new request body with the sanitized content. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.api.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.content.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
val plugin = createClientPlugin("no-emojis") {
    on(Send) {
        val newBody = when (val body = it.body) {
            is TextContent -> {
                val text = body.text.replace("x", "value") // An example of sanitizing
                TextContent(text, body.contentType, body.status)
            }

            else -> error("I don't know how to sanitize $body")
        }
        it.body = newBody
        proceed(it)
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Some(val x: Int)

suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        install(plugin)
    }
    val r = client.post("https://httpbin.org/post") {
        setBody(Some(123))
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    }
    println(r.bodyAsText())
}
```

Comment: thank you that actually works i am updating my question with full details of the solution

Comment: @Aleksi also can you give a solution for how to do this on all headers?

Comment: You can get and modify headers using the `it.headers` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aleksei Tirmam for his given solution I managed to do it.

```
const val REGEX_SANITIZE_EMOJIS: String = "[\\p{C}\\p{So}︀-️\\x{E0100}-\\x{E01EF}]+"
const val REGEX_CLEAN_SPACES: String = " {2,}"
const val PLUGIN_REMOVE_EMOJIS: String = "no more emojis"

val removeEmojiPlugin: ClientPlugin<Unit> = createClientPlugin(PLUGIN_REMOVE_EMOJIS) {

      val filterNonUtf8: (String) -> String = { text ->
        text
          .replace(Regex(REGEX_SANITIZE_EMOJIS), "")
          .replace(Regex(REGEX_CLEAN_SPACES), " ")
      }

      on(Send) {
        it.body = when (val body = it.body) {

          is TextContent -> {
            val text: String = body.text
              .replace(Regex(REGEX_SANITIZE_EMOJIS), "")
              .replace(Regex(REGEX_CLEAN_SPACES), " ")

            TextContent(text, body.contentType, body.status)
          }

          is FormDataContent -> {
            val parameters: Parameters = Parameters.build {
              body.formData.forEach { key, values ->
                val filteredValues: List<String> = values.map(filterNonUtf8)
                this.appendAll(key, filteredValues)
              }
            }

            FormDataContent(parameters)
          }

          is EmptyContent -> body
          else -> body
        }
        proceed(it)
      }
    }
```

and in your HTTP client install this plugin

```
  HttpClient { install(removeEmojiPlugin) }
```